# Unreasonably refused carriage by TfL

Tags: england-and-wales, police, transportation, public-transport

Suppose Bob takes his bike every day on the London Overground which he is entitled to do under the rules if it is not peak time. One day he goes to ride the train and his chain has broken and it is raining heavily out and he happens to be quite far from home. He is told by the tfl tube attendant that because his bike is not folding model it isn't allowed and because it is electrically assisted it must have a combustible battery so it wouldn't be allowed anyway.

Bob retrieves the official rules on his phone to show the station supervisor but the supervisor is not interested instead exhibiting a big sadistic grin while taking delight in the fact that he has the power to waste the time of another human being. He isn't interested in how he's mistaken about the official rules but calls the police.

Bob having been in this situation once before at another station eagerly awaited the police arrival as on that occasion the btp were reasonable and explained to the station manager how he had been mistaken on the rules so that Bob was allowed to ride.

On this occasion they were much more unreasonable and awful, and Bob was forced to wait for an hour after he had already touched in to the station but was being obstructed from entering with the big disabled turnstile being switched off to prevent his entry. The entire time this bully station manager stood smugly grinning. The London Overground employee came up from downstairs at one point and actually looked up the rules because he gathered that Bob had actually known what he was talking about and reasoned to the station supervisor that as Bob's bicycle was neither a scooter nor a unicycle, it should therefore be allowed on the train but the supervisor wouldn't hear any of it.

Further when asked for his name the man began putting his hands over his name badge before eventually deliberately turning it to face himself so that it could not be read.

When BTP arrive they explain that because TfL is a private entity they can change the rules arbitrarily and refuse to allow you on at their own discretion.

Yet this is hard to believe given the public funding and surely attached mandate which it receives from the government to provide a public service for all.

What is the actual legality here, and what requirement do TfL have to apply the rules evenly and uniformly?

What remedies does Bob have available for his wasted time, his refusal of carriage, the supervisor's concealment of his identity, general rude treatment, and the BTP's shockingly insulting accusation of his "wasting police time" by simply trying to explain the situation to reason with them upon their arrival, either against TfL, or against BTP?

Comment: Whats a TfL and a BTP? Please explain your acronyms

Comment: Transport for London and British transport police.

Comment: TfL is a local government body, not a private entity. Perhaps the 'private entity' is a franchisee operating the line.

Comment: @WeatherVane Even if TfL is a government body it's possible that its rules operate as if it were a private body.  If that is the case then it's highly unlikely that TfL delegates any authority it has to "change the rules arbitrarily and refuse to allow you on at their own discretion" to a station manager.  Therefore, a more likely road to vindication is to file a complaint concerning the station manager with TfL, which will probably treat it not as a violation of any law but as a disciplinary matter concerning an employee who has failed to follow policy.

Comment: @phoog what further clouds that government / private body question is that (despite the TfL branding) the Overground is actually operated for them by a private company (Arriva London Rail)

Comment: @motosubatsu Interesting.  I would suppose, however, that the contract of carriage (or other legal relationship between a passenger and the carrier) is with TfL, and that Arriva has no direct relationship with the passenger except as an agent of TfL.  Is that not the case?

Comment: That is what I said: train operators are franchises.

Comment: @phoog honestly I'm not sure exactly here the boundaries lie

Comment: Not a legal matter, but as a consumer issue, your best bet is to complain to the appropriate company according to their complaints procedure (providing copies of tickets etc if possible); they will often refund tickets in such situations. You should be able to find out who to complain to from the TfL website, whether it's TfL or some other entity.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a rant.

Comment: Was the traveller really called Joe, not Bob? These Alice, Bob, Charlie, Dave, etc names that you often see here are not mandatory.

Answer (score 12):

If we cut through all the entertaining colour commentary around Bob's experience then all that happened is TfL refused him permission to carry a specific item and according to the TfL [Conditions of Carriage](https://content.tfl.gov.uk/tfl-conditions-of-carriage.pdf):

> **9.2**  Staff can refuse permission for you to take any item onto our services. For example, you may be prevented from taking a bicycle on DLR services during the London Marathon.

So the rules around the times when non-folding bikes are permitted on the Overground  not withstanding there's a catch-all rule which allows them to refuse specific items on specific occasions for whatever reason they want.

> What remedies does Bob have available for his wasted time, his refusal of carriage, the supervisor's concealment of his identity, general rude treatment,

Realistically - none. The refusal may be harsh - but there's plenty of room in the conditions of carriage to allow it. A supervisor concealing his identity may be annoying but it's not *illegal*, nor is being rude.

> the BTP's shockingly insulting accusation of his "wasting police time" by simply trying to explain the situation to reason with them upon their arrival, either against TfL, or against BTP?

Probably nothing doing here either - the BTP aren't for what Bob's trying to use them for. I doubt they'd actually pursue Bob for wasting police time unless he makes a habit of doing it, but they've got a point. They're not the complaints department for TfL! It's like calling the police because McDonalds won't serve you at the drive through.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139208/discussion-on-answer-by-motosubatsu-unreasonably-refused-carriage-by-tfl).